# django: No module named entities.foo

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up my first django project. Within the project, I have created a package called 'domain'. Within the package 'domain', there is a folder called 'entities'. Within the 'entities' folder, there is a file called 'foo.py', which contains a class called 'Foo'.

I'm trying to import the class 'Foo' into another file (module?) I've tried pretty much every permutation I can think of. When I try this:

```
from domain.entities.foo import Foo
```

Eclipse stops highlighting the Foo class as unfound. It seems to be satisfied. But when I look at the page in a browser, I get an error screen:

```
Import Error at /[URL]
No module named entities.foo
```

Can anyone help? I am entirely out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly don't have a `__init__.py` empty file on each folder (package). If you are using Python 2.X, you need it.

```
domain
|---- __init__.py
|---- entities
|     |---- foo.py
|     |---- __init__.py
```

After that, you will be able to import the class `Foo` inside the module `domain.entities.foo`

```
from domain.entities.foo import Foo
```

Comment: Yes, 'entities' is a folder, not a package. But then, I don't know what a package is.

Comment: A package is a folder with an `__init__.py` empty file (Python 2.x). More information here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages